# MariaDB SQL Syntax error from SquirelL SQL Client

Tags: java, sql, ubuntu, mariadb, squirrel-sql

I am using SQuirelL client to connect to MariaDB. My OS is Ubuntu. I have downloaded the Mariadb driver (mariadb-java-client-1.5.2.jar) to the proper location and linked it in the SQuirelL client. I have setup a database, and am able to create tables in it. 
But things go south when i try creating any object where i use a DELIMITER. I have even tried with the mysql driver, mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar. but same error.

this is my SQL -

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION FortyTwo() RETURNS TINYINT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE x TINYINT;
 SET x = 42;
 RETURN x;
END 

//

DELIMITER ;
```

and this is the error -

```
    Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION FortyTwo() RETURNS TINYINT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DE' at line 1
Query is : DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION FortyTwo() RETURNS TINYINT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE x TINYINT
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064
Error occurred in:
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION FortyTwo() RETURNS TINYINT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE x TINYINT
```

**I will greatly appreciate any help ! Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

`DELIMITER` is not a valid MariaDB SQL command.
Look at the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sql-commands/). You won't find it there.

`DELIMITER` is a [MySQL Client command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html):

> ```
> mysql> help
>
> List of all MySQL commands:
> Note that all text commands must be first on line and end with ';'
> ...
> delimiter (\d) Set statement delimiter.
> ...
> ```

You generally don't need delimiters, since you only execute one command at a time when using JDBC.

They can be *batched* if needed for performance, but they should still be submitted to the JDBC driver one at a time.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! that was it ! i thought it should work just like MySQL.